# Firefox click recorder

Tags: javascript, python, firefox, record

I am working on a project of mine that will allow the user to launch a browser and start recording the clicks (xpath, css, click reference, combo-boxes, etc) so that the user would be able to playback the recording after their done. What i want to do is to build something that will record these clicks through xpath, url, or anything else. But i have prowled the internet for a method to create such program but i could not find anything. Only thing I found was selenium IDE (http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/), but I want to create my own, how can I access the browser and record the clicks or path that the user clicks on? Thanks!

Comment: selenium is open source and can do everything you are attempting to do youself, perhaps you could start there? http://seleniumhq.org/download/source.html

Comment: Is there a simple example, that just records what the user clicks on? I just dont understand the click recording concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to study [imacros for firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/imacros-for-firefox/).